# Install ZF2 modules on windows 7 by using composer.json

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, composer-php

I have just started to explore zf2 and trying to install modules. have downloaded zip for ZfcAdmin and ZfcUser and added them manually but no luck. I think it can be installed by using composer.phar but how I have skeleton application running perfectly.

I know php composer.phar self-update / install but how to write composer.json is my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the `composer.json` file with a text-editor of your choice. Then you'll be able to see the json formatted data, that will be passed to `composer.phar`

If you wish to add new modules, you'll see the `require: {}` block, to which you simply add the namespaces/modules you wish to include. For example extend your `composer.json` to something like this:

```
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
    "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.*"
}
```

Seeing this i install both `zend-developer-tools` and `zendframework` from the `zendframework` Git-Repositories and additionally i install `doctrine-orm-module` from `doctrine`-repository.

A little catch: Some repositories / modules are under heavy development and there will be no stable version yet. Personally i run with the additional parameter `"minimum-stability": "alpha",` to tell composer to include all alpha repositories for downloading.

If you just need a single alpha-version, you'd much likely need to re-write the `composer.json` a couple of times.

Last but not least, `php composer.phar update` will do the trick and you'll always be up to date with the repositories.

**Some additional notes for windows users**

- Sometimes Write-Permissions may be missing from command line. You can change this by running the command line with administrator privileges.
- If the PHP Command is not found, you may need to add the PATH to the PHP-Executable into your Environment-Variable `PATH`
- I wrote a detailed blog-post on how to keep ZF2 running via command line with git for windows 7 myself, so far this has covered most problems, you may want to [check out my Blogpost](http://samminds.com/2012/07/zend-framework-2-installation-on-xampp-for-windows/)

Hope this gets you running ;)

Comment: sam thanks for the answer one last thing , how can i find out 'namespaces/modules' for letsay ZfcAdmin module

Comment: usually it's `accountname/repositoryname` i.e.: in your cases it'd be `"zf-commons/zfc-user": "dev-master"` and `"zf-commons/zfc-admin": "dev-master"` - thing to note is, CamelCase gets turned into dash-separated-lowercase. Most modules also have installation instructions for composer like this: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser#with-composer